# Conditional expectation from trivariate joint PDF

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I have a multipart problem with an explicit PDF given, but really I am just looking for a hint or an idea to go on.

I am either given or have solved for the following:

1. Joint PDF: $$\frac{2}{ \pi}e^{x(y+z-x-4)-\frac{1}{2}(y^2+z^2)}, \ x \geq 0;\  y, z \in \mathbb{R}$$
2. Joint density for $X, Y$: $f_{X, Y}(x, y)$
3. The conditional expectation $E(Y| X= x)$

I am looking to solve for the conditional expectation $E(YZ|X=x)$. How would I proceed? Thank you.

Some thoughts (that could be very wrong): I know $f_Z$ can be obtained from integrating $f_{X, Y, Z}$ w.r.t. to $X$ and $Y$. But is $f_Z$ just $f_{X, Y, Z}/f_{X,Y}$? Then I can integrate $\frac{f_Z \cdot f_{X, Y}}{f_{X,Y}\cdot f_{X}}$?

The reason I am not doing the first part (integrating $x$ and $y$) is because there seems to be some sort of shortcut/logical progression from the way the questions are asked and I was wondering if I can make use of the previous parts that I have already done.

Comment: From the joint pdf, it looks like $Y, Z$ are conditionally independent given $X$. Also it looks like $Y, Z$ are symmetric. So it seems that $E[YZ|X = x] = E[Y|X = x]E[Z|X = x] = E[Y|X = x]^2$

Comment: @BGM Thank you for you observation about them being symmetric, it was very helpful. Is there a way to conclude the latter without showing conditional independence? I have previously shown that $E(Y|X = x) = x$, is knowing this and symmetry enough or is showing conditional independence necessary?

Comment: I made the claim that $Y, Z$ are conditionally independent given $X$ since it is quite obvious that the joint pdf can be factorized once $x$ is fixed. Thus we can make use of this fact to factorize the conditional expectation. If we cannot observe / use this fact, then we go through the regular way, first compute the conditional pdf $\displaystyle f_{Y,Z|X} = \frac {f_{X,Y,Z}} {f_X} $, and then compute the integral $\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} yzf_{Y,Z|X}(y,z|x)dydz$